# Monorepo with typescript path aliases

Tags: typescript, monorepo, ts-node

I am trying to set up a monorepo, with `turbo` and typescript aliases. All of the code in the monorepo will be written in typescript, and what I would want to achieve, is that during development, the code should be ran, as-is, without the need to build the packages and/or apps using it.

This is how my folder structure looks at the moment

```
+ apps
  + my-app
    + src
      - index.ts
    - package.json
    - tsconfig.json
+ packages
  + my-package
    + src
      - firstFile.ts
      - secondFile.ts
    - package.json
    - tsconfig.json
- package.json
```

Let's say, that that the "dev" script in `my-app/package.json` is using ts-node to run the `index.ts` file, like this:
`NODE_OPTIONS='--conditions=developement' ts-node src/index.ts`

The contents of the `my-app/package.json` are as follows:

```
// my-app/package.json
import {...} from 'my-package/src/firstFile'
...
```

Inside the `my-package` packages tsconfig file, I've set up a path alias, so that I can more easily import files from inside the package, that aliases `main` with `my-package/src` folder, something like this:

```
// packages/my-package/tsconfig.json
...
"compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
     "paths": {
       "main/*": ["./src/*"]
     }
},
...
```

And here is the `firstFile.ts`

```
//packages/my-package/src/firstFile.ts
import {someFunction} from 'main/secondFile';

...
```

When I try to run my app however, ts-node does not recognize the type aliases set by the package itself.

Here are some things that I've tried:

- I've tried using `tsconfig-paths` as well, registered it by modifying the `dev` script. When using it, type aliases that are present in `my-app/tsconfig.json` are recognized and used, but not the aliases present in `my-package/tsconfig.json`.
- I've realized that the problem might be is how ts-node is not compiling `my-package`, because it is loaded from the `node_modules` folder, so I've also tried adding `--skipIgnore` flag to it, but the error was the same - when node encounters the import statement in `firstFile.ts`, it errors out, saying that it can't find `main/secondFile.ts`.

Is there really no way to make this work, without pre-building each package, before running the dev server?